# UIScrollView ContentSize crashes my code

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have this line of code in my app:

```
NSLog(@"%f , %f",safeZoneTutorialView.frame.size.height,safeZoneListView.frame.size.height);
[safeZonesScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, safeZoneTutorialView.frame.size.height + 30 + safeZoneListView.frame.size.height)];
```

The output log is:

```
2012-09-21 09:44:52.148 Locator[22143:11603] 100.000000 , 231.250000
2012-09-21 09:44:54.176 Locator[22143:11603] -[userProfileSafeZones setContentSize:]:               unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bc1290
2012-09-21 09:44:54.176 Locator[22143:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[userProfileSafeZones setContentSize:]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x7bc1290'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15d2022 0x1056cd6 0x15d3cbd 0x1538ed0 0x1538cb2 0x1bdf7 0x1a8f6 0x15d3e99 0x1bc14e   0x1bc0e6 0x262ade 0x262fa7 0x262266 0x47da1a 0x15a699e 0x153d640 0x15094c6 0x1508d84 0x1508c9b 0x14bb7d8 0x14bb88a 0x1b9626 0x2252 0x21c5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Did I enter the command incorrectly?

This is the rest of this ScrollView data:

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"userProfileSafeZones" owner:self options:nil];
safeZonesScrollView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
safeZonesScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,145,320,335);
safeZonesScrollView.alpha = 0;
```

And i'm not sure if i should "alloc init" this scrollview (it crashes if i do and it crashes if i don't).

Thanks.

Comment: userProfileSafeZones is a viewController of UIScrollView? And safeZonesScrollView is an ivar to a UIScrollview?

Comment: if your loading a view controller from the bundle why to set its frame size?? and if its a scroll view.. i dont understand how u can load a component from a bundle.. i've never done that...

Comment: load a component from a bundle is working, but i agree the frame setting is not needed. The userProfileSafeZones and safeZonesScrollView are both classes. These are not the point. I did notice that a if i pull the contentSize function before loading the bundle does work. Why doesn't it let me do it afterwards?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [[userProfileSafeZones class] description]);